# NPAPI: preferred windowing model (windowed/windowless/xembed) for non-visual plugin

Tags: plugins, npapi, browser-plugin

I'm creating an NPAPI plugin that isn't supposed to have a UI (for use from Javascript only). What windowing model should I use (windowed/windowless/xembed) to support as many browsers (and browser versions) as possible?

I currently implement the following functions:

- `NPP_SetWindow`: do nothing, return `NPERR_NO_ERROR`
- `NPP_Event`: do nothing, return `kNPEventNotHandled` (0)
- `NPP_SetValue`: do nothing, return `NPERR_NO_ERROR`
- `NPP_GetValue`: if asked for `NPPVpluginNeedsXEmbed`, answer yes if the browser supports it (`NPNVSupportsXEmbedBool`), no otherwise

For this plugin I am supporting Linux & Windows only for now. The `NPPVpluginNeedsXEmbed` was necessary for [Chrome on Linux (bug 38229)](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38229), however some old versions may not support it as [the MDC page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XEmbed_Extension_for_Mozilla_Plugins) says that the sample plugin for XEmbed is only supported on Firefox 2.0+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common that I have seen is to not care at all about the windowing mode and set the object tag to 1x1 (you can try 0x0, but I've seen browser bugs related to that) size, in which case it doesn't really matter what window mode you use. However, I would do windowless myself since it won't ever cause the trademark block that floats over all other DOM elements that a normal windowed (XEmbed or not) plugin gives you.

This is what [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) does if the FB_GUI_DISABLED flag is set.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the 1x1 size. Saves me the trouble of finding it out the hard way :). Do you know which browser versions support windowless on X11?

Comment: as far as I know all of them (that are reasonably current) do; worst case, though, would be that you tell it to do windowless and it will return an error. That error would just force you into windowed mode. Since you're going to want to size your plugin small either way it probably isn't a big deal.